# yardoc: exclude comments from documentation

Tags: ruby, documentation, yardoc

in Ruby, several times I'll separate sections of code with the following, so that I can quickly scan the code for an section of code.

```
... methods 

# 
# ------------------------------- (Some message)
#

... methods
```

This is not intended for yarddoc to document.

Does anyone know how to exclude this from being presented in code documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Include an extra newline between `(some message)` and `... methods`. Two newlines break the association between the message and the following block.

(As answered in [yard#484](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/484))